# Convert Caffe CNN to Feature Extractor

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I have to use a CNN model to extract features from images. I am using a trained model called Caffenet.

On Caffe, it is very easy to extract features after running the image through the CNN model. For example, if I want features extracted by the "conv5" layer, I simply call the method:

```
features = net.blobs['conv5'].data[0, : , : , :]
```

However, the tricky part is I need to use a 3rd party conversion tool to convert the model so that it can run on my mobile device. After converting the model, I cannot access the output of layers inside the model. I only get the final output, which in this case are classifications, and they are not what I need.

To get the model directly output features from the "conv5" layer, which is the final convolutional layer, I went inside the `deploy.prototxt` file and deleted all layers after the "conv5" layer, so "conv5" effectively became the final output layer. However, after doing so, the feature values I get are completely different from the feature values I had gotten before I changed the prototxt file.

My suspicion is that even though I changed the architecture by deleting layers in `deploy.prototxt`, I cannot change the weights inside the `caffenet.caffemodel` file. I am not sure why this would be a problem since the weights for layers after "conv5" would just not be used. I am not sure why this would change the output of "conv5".

How I can change a trained model to directly output features from the final convolutional layer?

Comment: it is difficult to answer such question since it is not clear what "conversion" your model is undergoing when you port it to mobile. Generally speaking, removing top layers from `deploy.prototxt` should not affect the feature values of preceding layers. So, your `conv5` features should remain the same. The usual suspect in this case is the input transformation: does your ported model subtract mean and scale the pixel in the **exact** same way as your original model? Do you get **exactly** the same class predictions (probabilities) using the ported mobile model?

Comment: look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38312250/1714410), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40480511/1714410),

Comment: BTW, do you have `BathNorm` layers in your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason may be that some layers after the "conv5" layer will update or change the top blob of conv5. These layers include relu layers or batch_norm layers since these layers usually use in-place operations. So you'd better check the deploy prototxt and keep batch_norm and relu layers after conv5  unchanged.

Comment: I kept the relu layer and now it's outputting correctly!